# Am I mapping ports wrong on this API call from a Docker container to a locally running API?

Tags: node.js, docker, api, .net-core, containers

Some more context: I have a simple dotnetcore API endpoint (simple GET endpoint that, for now, just responds with a HTTP 200 statuscode). I want to call that endpoint from a NodeJs script running inside a Docker container. Then endpoint when running from Visual Studio is:
https://localhost:44350/api/commands

The NodeJs script:

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios.get('https://localhost:8080/api/commands')
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.status)
    console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install
RUN npm install axios

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "script.js" ]
```

I build the image as such:

```
docker build -t <mydockerid>/jsscriptexecution . --no-cache
```

And run as such:

```
docker run -p 44350:8080 -it --rm <mydockerid>/jsscriptexecution
```

When I execute that line, I get:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:44350: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
> time="2021-01-27T13:30:13+01:00" level=error msg="error waiting for container: context canceled"

I assume I'm doing something wrong mapping the ports, or maybe the concept of "localhost" is not recognized in Docker. I replaced localhost by my machine's IP, but that also doesn't work. I am very new to Docker, but I can't imagine being the first dealing with this kind of issue..?

As a sidenote, if I replace the url in the axios.get call by a publicly available API like 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY', I get a result back without any issues. So it's not so much that I can not call any exterior API, but more (I think) that the "localhost" part of it is not recognized..?

Comment: Is Visual Studio still running and listening on port 44350 when you `docker run` the container?  That could cause this port conflict.  If the container is just a client, (a) you don't need the `-p` option at all (it is only for accepting connections into server-type containers) and (b) in fact `localhost` works differently in Docker (it is usually "the current container", not another container or the host).

Comment: Yes, of course it is still listening: I want the NodeJs script to call my dotnetcore api that is at that time listening outside of the container, that is the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption: there are two docker containers.

1. .NET Core service
2. NodeJS app

When you have more than one container things get a lot easy when you create a `docker-compose.yml` file

The advantage is that it'll create a common network between those two docker containers.

Another point:
there are two worlds when you are running containers.

1. Inside docker (and docker network)
2. The host machine

the -p <host>:<container>
when you are accessing from the host machine. use the host port
when you are accessing from the container use the container port.

Summary answer:

1. create docker compose
2. change localhost:8000 in nodejs to webapi:8000 (webapi is the name in docker-compose)

Comment: Well, the starting assumption is not wrong (although I have thought about going with that approach). The .NET Core service is not running in a container, but from Visual Studio (just debugging). I may try deploying it to its own container and going the docker-compose route though.